# What is the reason for Django- Page not found /login error

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project,upon running the application with  `python3 manage.py runserver`. I am able to get the login page,after logging in,I should be able to see the home/index page however I get an error something like

````
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Using the URLconf defined in leadgen.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

index [name='index_view']
[name='login_view']
add [name='add_view']
base [name='base_view']
company [name='company_view']
insigths [name='insights_view']
master [name='master_view']
leads [name='leads_view']
settings [name='settings_view']
team [name='team_view']
admin/
The current path, login, didn't match any of these.```
Leadgen is my project and Leadgen_app is its application. This is how I have written the urls.py for the application
````

leadgen_app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.login_view, name='login_view'),
    path('index', views.index_view, name='index_view'),
    path('add', views.add_view, name='add_view'),
    path('base', views.base_view, name='base_view'),
    path('company', views.company_view, name='company_view'),
    path('insigths', views.enrich_view, name='insights_view'),
    path('master', views.master_view, name='master_view'),
    path('leads', views.leads_view, name='leads_view'),
    path('settings', views.settings_view, name='settings_view'),
    path('team', views.team_view, name='team_view'),
]
```

and this is how I have written the urls for leadgen project

````
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('leadgen_app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]```

How do I solve this error? Please help.
````

Comment: You don't have a `login` route in the `urls.py`. The error is causing because the requested url is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login`

Comment: @MjZac if I add it,I am unable to login as well.

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` Does this url take you to your login page? Also make sure to end your url patterns with a `/` (except empty ones) unless you have set `APPEND_SLASH = False` in your settings.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat 8000/ takes me to my login page,after login is successful it should take me to index.html which is my homepage/dashboard of the application but after login at 8000/ it goes to 8000/login when it should go to 8000/home and display my homepage.

Comment: @technophile_3 You need to redirect to the correct url, that's a problem with your views. Also note the missing slashes in your url pattern might be causing trouble here. When Django finds a url not ending in slash it redirects the user automatically to the same url with slash appended, turning any POST request into GET (unable to keep post params while redirecting).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for your timely help, I shall do it.